# Create a job and update table every 3 mins in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2008

I have a script which creates a table every 3 minutes in SQL Server using pandas.

```
curentTempDF.to_sql('currentTemperature',sql_engine,index=False,if_exists='replace', schema="dbo")
```

Table `currentTemperature`:

```
Code    date    temperature
```

And in SQL Server, I need to create a job which runs every 3 minutes and updates temperature table with the all the values of current temperature table.

Table `Temperature`:

```
Code    date    temperature
```

For example: update table temperature, select * from current temperature.

How do I do that?

Comment: Any code to show for the job?

Comment: use `SQL Server Agent` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Let's start by actually creating, testing, and verifying an update statement that is both syntactically correct and produces the correct result. When you get that working, you can then address automating it. The first thing to consider is if you actually need to schedule this and, if so, on what period? Why not update your "real" table when the "current" table is modified? And consider that you should only update changed values for efficiency considerations - not just blindly update everything.

Comment: If you need to schedule a job to run every 3 minutes, a little google effort finds [many suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+schedule+job+to+run+every+minute&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&oq=sql+server+schedule+job+to+run+every+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i22i29i30l3.14981j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as well as comments about whether this is a good idea.